# Display Wordpress username on Vue Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a vue project which is a wordpress plugin. The plugin is pretty basic example of couunter increment on button click and works fine on wordpress admin dashboard.

I have added another heading to the frontend in vue called `username` I want to display the wordpress username in the Home.vue which is the frontend of the plugin with the increment button.

This is my Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="vue-demo-site">
    <h1>Hello Vue</h1>
    <h2>Counter: {{ count }}</h2>
    <h2> Username: </h2>
    <button @click="increment">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const count = ref(0);

function increment() {
  count.value++;
}

</script>

<style scoped>
  #vue-demo-site {
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 15px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: purple;
    margin: 0;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
  }
  button {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: purple;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

The following is my plugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: KomoDeFi App
Plugin URI: https://komodefi.com/
Description: A description for komodefi app
Version: 0.1
Author: KomoDeFi
Author URI: https://komodefi.com
License: GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: textdomain
Domain Path: /languages
*/

/**
 * Copyright (c) 2023 KomoDeFi. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Released under the GPL license
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php
 *
 * This is an add-on for WordPress
 * http://wordpress.org/
 * 
 * Inspired by: https://github.com/tareq1988/vue-wp-starter
 *
 * **********************************************************************
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 * **********************************************************************
 */

// don't call the file directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * KomoDeFi_App class
 *
 * @class KomoDeFi_App The class that holds the entire KomoDeFi_App plugin
 */
final class KomoDeFi_App {

    /**
     * Plugin version
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $version = '0.1';

    /**
     * Holds various class instances
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $container = array();

    /**
     * Constructor for the KomoDeFi_App class
     *
     * Sets up all the appropriate hooks and actions
     * within our plugin.
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->define_constants();

        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activate' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivate' ) );

        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init_plugin' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the KomoDeFi_App() class
     *
     * Checks for an existing KomoDeFi_App() instance
     * and if it doesn't find one, creates it.
     */
    public static function init() {
        static $instance = false;

        if ( ! $instance ) {
            $instance = new KomoDeFi_App();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Magic getter to bypass referencing plugin.
     *
     * @param $prop
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get( $prop ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $prop, $this->container ) ) {
            return $this->container[ $prop ];
        }

        return $this->{$prop};
    }

    /**
     * Magic isset to bypass referencing plugin.
     *
     * @param $prop
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __isset( $prop ) {
        return isset( $this->{$prop} ) || isset( $this->container[ $prop ] );
    }

    /**
     * Define the constants
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function define_constants() {
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_VERSION', $this->version );
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_FILE', __FILE__ );
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_PATH', dirname( PLUGINBASE_FILE ) );
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES', PLUGINBASE_PATH . '/includes' );
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_URL', plugins_url( '', PLUGINBASE_FILE ) );
        define( 'PLUGINBASE_ASSETS', PLUGINBASE_URL . '/assets' );
    }

    /**
     * Load the plugin after all plugis are loaded
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_plugin() {
        $this->includes();
        $this->init_hooks();
    }

    /**
     * Placeholder for activation function
     *
     * Nothing being called here yet.
     */
    public function activate() {

        $installed = get_option( 'pluginbase_installed' );

        if ( ! $installed ) {
            update_option( 'pluginbase_installed', time() );
        }

        update_option( 'pluginbase_version', PLUGINBASE_VERSION );
    }

    /**
     * Placeholder for deactivation function
     *
     * Nothing being called here yet.
     */
    public function deactivate() {

    }

    /**
     * Include the required files
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function includes() {

        require_once PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES . '/Assets.php';

        if ( $this->is_request( 'admin' ) ) {
            require_once PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES . '/Admin.php';
        }

        if ( $this->is_request( 'frontend' ) ) {
            require_once PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES . '/Frontend.php';
        }

        if ( $this->is_request( 'ajax' ) ) {
            // require_once PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES . '/class-ajax.php';
        }

        require_once PLUGINBASE_INCLUDES . '/Api.php';
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the hooks
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_hooks() {

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init_classes' ) );

        // Localize our plugin
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'localization_setup' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate the required classes
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_classes() {

        if ( $this->is_request( 'admin' ) ) {
            $this->container['admin'] = new App\Admin();
        }

        if ( $this->is_request( 'frontend' ) ) {
            $this->container['frontend'] = new App\Frontend();
        }

        if ( $this->is_request( 'ajax' ) ) {
            // $this->container['ajax'] =  new App\Ajax();
        }

        $this->container['api'] = new App\Api();
        $this->container['assets'] = new App\Assets();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize plugin for localization
     *
     * @uses load_plugin_textdomain()
     */
    public function localization_setup() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'pluginbase', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
    }

    /**
     * What type of request is this?
     *
     * @param  string $type admin, ajax, cron or frontend.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function is_request( $type ) {
        switch ( $type ) {
            case 'admin' :
                return is_admin();

            case 'ajax' :
                return defined( 'DOING_AJAX' );

            case 'rest' :
                return defined( 'REST_REQUEST' );

            case 'cron' :
                return defined( 'DOING_CRON' );

            case 'frontend' :
                return ( ! is_admin() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) && ! defined( 'DOING_CRON' );
        }
    }

} // KomoDeFi_App

$pluginbase = KomoDeFi_App::init();
```

This is my admin.php which takes the div from App.Vue routed to Home.vue as you can see at the end.

```
<?php
namespace App;

/**
 * Admin Pages Handler
 */
class Admin {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'admin_menu' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Register our menu page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function admin_menu() {
        global $submenu;

        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $slug       = 'komodefi';

        $hook = add_menu_page( __( 'KomoDeFi', 'textdomain' ), __( 'KomoDeFi', 'textdomain' ), $capability, $slug, [ $this, 'plugin_page' ], 'dashicons-layout' );

        if ( current_user_can( $capability ) ) {
            $submenu[ $slug ][] = array( __( 'App', 'textdomain' ), $capability, 'admin.php?page=' . $slug . '#/' );
            $submenu[ $slug ][] = array( __( 'Options', 'textdomain' ), $capability, 'admin.php?page=' . $slug . '#/options' );
        }

        add_action( 'load-' . $hook, [ $this, 'init_hooks'] );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize our hooks for the admin page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_hooks() {
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Load scripts and styles for the app
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pluginbase-admin' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'pluginbase-style' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pluginbase-admin' );
    }

    /**
     * Render our admin page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function plugin_page() {
        echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="pluginbase-admin-app"></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Values you need to migrate from PHP to JS can be printed as a inline-script and later read by your application on load.